# Prevent triggering two mouse events on html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a function that on mousedown or mouseover, cells get highlighted or changes are made within the cells.

All changes to the cells work well, except for when I try to empty the text in a span within the cell (.number_searches), using a jquery functions of .html .text or .empty.  Doing that causes the code to fire a double-click (one for mousedown, one for mouseover)

Is there a way to empty the ".number_searches" span without triggering both the mousedown and mouseover event (2 clicks)?

The following line in the triggered click function (.dosearches), causes the issue:

```
area.find('.number_searches').html("&nbsp;");
```

```js
$(function() {
  let isMouseDown = false;
  let hasBeenClicked = false;
  let isHighlighted;
  $("#tablegrid").on('mousedown', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
    if (hasBeenClicked === false) {
      $(this).find('.dosearches').trigger('click');
      hasBeenClicked = true;
    }
    return false; // prevent text selection
  })
  $("#tablegrid").on('mouseover', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      if (hasBeenClicked === false) {
        $(this).find('.dosearches').trigger('click');
        hasBeenClicked = true;
      }
    }
  })
  // May or may not need this part depending on your app design
  $("#tablegrid").on('mouseout', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    hasBeenClicked = false;
  })
  $("#tablegrid").bind('selectstart', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    return false;
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
    hasBeenClicked = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="search_juris_cell" class="nohighlight">
      <div class="search_checkbox_section">
        <div class="dosearchescheckbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="dosearches" class="dosearches">
        </div>
        <span class="number_searches">5 searches</span>
        <div class="search_checkbox_types">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify this question? I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to a [mcve]. Why divs in cells? Not recommended. Also use on instead of deprecated bind everyehere

Comment: I want to clear the html in this span <span class="number_searches"> when the cell is clicked.  But, it's triggering 2 clicks (mousedown and mouseover) event.  The ".html" javascript tag is triggering the 2 clicks

Comment: Updated the question to try to make it clearer.